# Como armazenar e recuperar a URL anterior dentro do Cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

O script todo, fica na barra de favoritos/marcadores, denominado: [Bookmarklet](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)

Eu já elaborei o `script`. Veja:

## Antes c/ referrer

```
javascript: var URL = document.referrer; location.href = URL;
```

## Agora c/ cookie

```
javascript: var URL = window.location; link = document.cookie; link = URL; location.href = link;
```

Infelizmente não tô conseguindo imitar o *método* `referrer` com um `cookie`. Seria esse meu interesse.

Alguém tem uma idéia de como referenciar uma URL anterior sem utilizar o *método* `document.referrer`?

Comment: Uma outra maneira possivel seria guardar nos cookies uma referencia para o link anterior, quando quiser é só utilizar ele. Assim vc pode reduzir a quantidade de parametros passador por GET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar um *Cookie* para fazer isso. Tem em conta que um *Cookie* não é seguro.

Para usar um *Cookie* deves usar no formato `chave=valor;` pois assim podes juntar vários cookies e sempre sabes qual é qual.

Assim neste caso, para escrever:

```
document.cookie = 'ultimoUrl=' + window.location.href;
```

Para ler, precisas de tirar o valor da string do `document.cookie` e podes fazer assim:

```
function lerCookie(nome) {
    var regex = new RegExp('(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)' + nome + '\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$');
    return document.cookie.replace(regex, "$1");
}

document.cookie = 'MeuCookie=SOpt;';
console.log(lerCookie('MeuCookie')); // 'SOpt'
```

**jsFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/dhmwsxuq/

Comment: Grato pelo feedback!

Comment: @diegofm Me perdoe a ignorância mas, comigo da erro. Agora pouco limpei o historico juntamente com cookies e cache do navegador, e por fim acabei reinicializando o PC. E continua não acessando [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhmwsxuq/), mas em todo caso esta tudo bem apenas estou atualizando meu tópico, como de costume fico um tanto preocupado se outros também estão tendo o mesmo problema.

Comment: @DiegoHenrique estranho, vou pedir mais alguém para testar.

Comment: @diegofm Ja descobri o porque não conseguia acessar o exemplo de _Sergio_ - [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhmwsxuq/). Sempre que você acessa um site na Internet, eles iniciam por "HTTP" ou "HTTPS". Ambos são o mesmo Protocolo de Transferência de Hipertexto, porém, com um “S” a mais resulta na palavra: Seguro. Mas no meu caso eu preciso reitrar o "S" deixando-o sem somente **http://**

Answer (score 3):

Se o intuito é so redirecionar via "Favoritos" utilize isto:

```
// Pega o link atual
var link = window.location.href; 

// Redireciona para o site contendo o link
window.open("http://9xbuddy.com/download?url="+link);
```

Final:

```
javascript: var link=window.location.href;window.open("http://9xbuddy.com/download?url="+link);
```

Faça o mesmo que pediu para fazer, terá o mesmo resultado sem qualquer página ou HTML sendo injetado ou criado. ;)

Supostamente para suportar o Favicon criando os tais elementos:

```
$('head').html("<link rel='image_src' href='https://9xbuddy.com/img/9xbuddy.jpg'><script>window.open('http://9xbuddy.com/download?url='+window.location.href, '_self');</script>");
```

Neste caso é necessário carregar o JQuery, assim resultará em:

```
javascript:(function(e,a,g,h,f,c,b,d){if(!(f=e.jQuery)||g>f.fn.jquery||h(f)){c=a.createElement("script");c.type="text/javascript";c.src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/"+g+"/jquery.min.js";c.onload=c.onreadystatechange=function(){if(!b&&(!(d=this.readyState)||d=="loaded"||d=="complete")){h((f=e.jQuery).noConflict(1),b=1);f(c).remove()}};a.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild(c)}})(window,document,"1.3.2",function($,L){$('head').html("<link rel='image_src' href='https://9xbuddy.com/img/9xbuddy.jpg'><script>window.open('http://9xbuddy.com/download?url='+window.location.href, '_self');</script>");});
```

- Nenhuma das três opções apresentou o Favion no navegador testado, porém o último aqui mencionado possui um comportamento similar, não sei até que ponto é suficiente.

Comment: Eu testei adicionar o seu código "como está" e não apresenta nenhum favicon. Tentei elaborar algo semelhante ao que ocorre, injetando um `<script>` e um `<link>`, usando o JQuery, mas pode usar somente Javascript puro, por rapidez fiz em JQuery. Estou editando nesse momento.

Comment: Esse código que postou, que cria o elemento e redireciona, apresenta o favicon corretamente ou nem isso? Antes achava que o problema era só redirecionar, depois notei que precisava redirecionar E possuir um favicon. Agora apenas quero saber se ao menos o Favicon está funcionando. Em testes nem o Favicon foi apresentado, em com o JQuery e nem com o que está na postagem. Procurei por alguns exemplos "mais elaborados", como este: http://del.icio.us/tools. Também não apresenta nenhum favicon. Acredito que não há como obter isso. Uma alternativa seria criar um extensão/plugin para o navegador.